# Overwrite files in nuget

Tags: nuget

I have a nuget package that references other nuget packages. One of these "inner" packages has a security hole. How can I - without changing the package - overwrite the "inner" reference? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to directly reference that package in your project/package so that the fixed version is "nearer" to the project that is being restored.

However you cannot change the package identifier, only the version being used (and in worst case szenarios, create your own package from a fork with the same id/name but a custom version - e.g. `1.2.3-workaround.1`)

Comment: Hi, directly? Can you give me a hint?